# How to create DDL from output columns in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have DataFlow task which has been created programmatically,

The data source connected with DBMS via OLE DB Provider, 
I can get output columns from the source and map then with input columns of destination component.

But I can't invoke ReinitializeMetaData() for destination component because destination table doesn't exist.

Therefore, I want to get DDL from output columns for creating the table.
Maybe, someone knows which functionality is provided in SSIS for this purpose? 
Thanks in  advance

Comment: The only way I can think of is with a script task.

Comment: It seems like it is the only way. I'm forced to write own code which analyzes data type of each column and gets appropriate DLL based on given information